# Search number in string, distinguish number of digits

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

The user enters a formula as a string in cell B1 using some of the variables in cells A1:A16. I want to create a conditional formatting rule to highlight the variables used.

[image]

I used this which works fine for c1 to c9. As you can see in the picture, it doesn't work for c16 because it highlights both c1 and c16.

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A1,$B$1))
```

Comment: Try: `=XMATCH(A1:A16,TEXTSPLIT($B$1,{"#";"$";"(";")";"*";"+";"-";"/";"=";"@"}))`

Comment: Sorry the one above will not work in conditional formatting because we cannot use reference operators in conditional formatting. Hence create a range of those reference operators and use this formula in Conditional formatting. `=XMATCH(A1:A16,TEXTSPLIT($B$1,$F$2:$F$11))` where `F2:F11` refers to `#`, `+`,`$`,`(`,`)`,`*`,`-`,`/`,`=`,`@`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented above, the formula given in the first comment will not work with `Conditional Formatting`, since **reference operators** can't be used within `Conditional Formatting`. Hence create a range of those operators and use the formula in `Conditional Formatting`.

---

[image]

---

• Formula used in conditional formatting:

```
=XMATCH(A1:A16,TEXTSPLIT($B$1,$F$2:$F$11))
```

---

Where `F2:F11`

| Operators |
| --- |
| # |
| $ |
| ( |
| ) |
| * |
| + |
| - |
| / |
| = |
| @ |

---

Here is another example.

[image]

---

Answer (score 0):

For all excel versions (but it works only with same length strings)

[image]

```vb
=IFERROR(SEARCH(MID($B$1;SEARCH(A1;$B$1)+LEN(A1);1);" /*+-()";1);0)>0
```

You can add more characters here: " /*+-()" eg " /*+-()=%"

**ANOTHER TRY USING VBA**
I am using excel 2019, despite trying to fix the formula, it was not possible, the only way I found is through VB.

```vb
Public Function LK(s As String, sToMatch As String) As Boolean
   LK = s Like sToMatch
End Function
```

and usage for conditional formatting:

```vb
=LK($B$1&" ";"*" & A1 & "[!0123456789]*")
```

[image]

Comment: this doesn't work with "c16+c1"

Comment: @TeodorPatriche have you tried the one I have posted it does works with `C16+C1`

Comment: You are right, it works only with same length strings, or if "largers" are after "smaller" ones...